# Change (calculated) Colors of Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors

I want to change our website which includes the feature of displaying a Highchart (pie/donut)
Sadly I have to insight about the initial setup and can only work with the code in front of me (enormous file called highchart.js)

It seems like the colors are calculated based on a start value - and for each section/stop the color gets brigther.
But I just can't find where the "initial" color (variable?) is set or calculated.

I really just need to change the initial color value (I am fine with the colors getting brigther for each stop)
Is this something I can do directly in the highchart.js file?

Thanks ahead!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use *color axis* module for this, to change the initial color you need to use the `colorAxis.colorMin` properties. In addition, you also need to define `colorAxis.colorMax`.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  colorAxis: {
    minColor: '#fbb7b7',
    maxColor: '#ff0707'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/coloraxis.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pvh51zf3/

**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.minColor
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.maxColor